# How to extract external collaborators from Azure AD?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant

I need to extract the external tenants' (collaborators) data like name, domain, etc. which are linked with my Azure AD tenant. I cannot find any endpoint for that in the Microsoft Graph API. IS there any way to extract that data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Graph end point (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains) in Graph Explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer